# WPF Sparrow Chart

Tags: c#, wpf

Hello i've got a problem with generating a simple chart with Sparrow Toolkit in WPF. It's my XAML

```
<Window x:Class="GeneratorWPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:sparrow="http://sparrowtoolkit.codeplex.com/wpf"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Generator" Height="500" Width="1000" Loaded="button1_Click">
<Grid>
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="79,12,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <Label Content="Wariancja" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Label Content="Średnia" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,46,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Label Content="Przedział" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,80,0,0" Name="label3" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="79,46,0,0" Name="textBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="79,85,0,0" Name="textBox3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <Button Content="Generuj" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="380,13,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
    <sparrow:SparrowChart Theme="Grayscale" OverlayMode="SeriesFirst" Width="800" Height="300" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Name="chart">
        <sparrow:SparrowChart.Legend>
            <sparrow:Legend Header="Legend" LegendPosition="Outside" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" ShowIcon="True"></sparrow:Legend>
        </sparrow:SparrowChart.Legend>
        <sparrow:SparrowChart.XAxis>
            <sparrow:LinearXAxis MinValue="0" MaxValue="10" MajorTicksPosition="Cross"></sparrow:LinearXAxis>
        </sparrow:SparrowChart.XAxis>
        <sparrow:SparrowChart.YAxis>
            <sparrow:LinearYAxis MinValue="0" MaxValue="10" MajorTicksPosition="Cross"></sparrow:LinearYAxis>
        </sparrow:SparrowChart.YAxis>
    </sparrow:SparrowChart>
</Grid>
```

And .cs

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //float wariancja = 0;
    //float srednia = 0;
    //int przedzial = 0;
    textBox1.Text = "asdasd";
    chart.Series["as"];

    var point = new Sparrow.Chart.ChartPoint();
    var asss = new Sparrow.Chart.AreaSeries()
    {
        Points = new Point()
        {
            X = 1,
            Y = 4
        },
    };
    var serie = new SeriesBase();
    chart.Series.Add();
}
```

I'm trying to create object but nothings work. Can someone help me? Can i use only cs to generate chart? I need to use bind ? I'm start with WPF and don't really know about it too much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You assign `point`, `asss` and `serie` but you never use them.
2. `chart.Series["as"];` has no effect.
3. `chart.Series.Add();` looks wrong, should that be `chart.Series.Add(point);`?

Comment: I said i need help with this :)